# How to use nose's assert_raises?

Tags: python, nosetests

I've searched for documentation, but couldn't find any. There were a couple that didn't explain much.

Can someone explain to me Nose's

```
assert_raises(what should I put here?)
```

function and how to use it?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `assert_raises()` function tests to make sure a function call raises a specified exception when presented with certain parameters.

For example, if you had a function `add` that adds two numbers, it should probably raise a `TypeError` when you pass it, say, an integer and a string.  So:

```
from nose.tools import assert_raises

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

assert_raises(TypeError, add, 2, "0")
```

The first argument is the exception type you expect. The second is the function to call. The rest of the arguments will be passed to the function (in this case, they will become `x` and `y` inside the function).

If the expected exception is raised by the function, the assertion passes.

Comment: Okay thanks!But do you also know a links for a good nose documentation where I can checkout other Nose functions such as assert_equal, assert_raises!@kindall

Comment: I had trouble finding that, too. You can try `help(assert_rases)` though.

Comment: A bit hidden, but http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#module-nose.tools first paragraph states: "... and all of the same assertX methods found in unittest.TestCase (only spelled in PEP 8 fashion, so assert_equal rather than assertEqual).". Here is that list: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#assert-methods

Comment: install pydoc. Then  `pydoc nose.tools` will show you the manual. :D

Answer (score 98):

While the accepted answer is correct, I think there is a better use to `assert_raises` method.

If you simply want to assert that an exception occurs, it's probably simpler and cleaner to use `@raises` syntax.

```
@raises(HTTPError)
def test_exception_is_raised:
    call_your_method(p1, p2)
```

However, assume you want to do bit more with the raised exception, for example: we need to assert that raised HTTPError is of type **401: Unauthorized**, instead of **500: Server Error**.

In such a situation above syntax is not that helpful, we should use the `assert_raises` but in a different way.
If we do not pass it a `callable` as the second parameter `assert_raises` will return back a context which we can use to further test the exception details.

```
def test_exception_is_raised:
    with assert_raises(HTTPError) as cm:
         call_your_method(p1, p2)
    ex = cm.exception # raised exception is available through exception property of context
    ok_(ex.code == 401, 'HTTPError should be Unauthorized!')
```

Comment: Thanks taught me something new.

Comment: I would like to see the message of the exception. The ex i get from cm.exception has a blank ex.message. The exception is however raised with a message. What is going wrong?