# assert_raises() from nose.tools won't work right

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm halfway through the book Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw. The book doesn't have any coverage or documentation for the function `assert_raises()`.

So I tried to run this test:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48.parser import *

def test_except():
    raw_sentence = [('stop', 'the'), ('noun', 'bear'), ('verb', 'kill')]
    assert_raises(ParserError, parse_sentence(raw_sentence))
```

Here's the error when I tried to run `nosetests`:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.parser_tests.test_except
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "####/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "####/ex48/tests/parser_tests.py", line 8, in test_except
    assert_raises(ParserError, parse_sentence(raw_sentence))
  File "####/ex48/ex48/parser.py", line 69, in parse_sentence
    obj = parse_object(word_list)
  File "####/ex48/ex48/parser.py", line 53, in parse_object
    raise ParserError("Expected a noun or direction next.")
 ParserError: Expected a noun or direction next.

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 8 tests in 0.008s

 FAILED (errors=1)
```

Here is where the exception is coming from:

```
def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')

    if peek(word_list) == 'verb':
       return match(word_list, 'verb')
    else:
       raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

The call to `parse_sentence(raw_sentence)` is expected to fail. The `assert_raises()` should work properly, but it doesn't catch the raised exception from `parse_verb()` yielding a failed test. What do you think is/are the problem/s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `parse_sentence()` directly.  Instead, pass it as an argument.

```
assert_raises(ParserError, parse_sentence, raw_sentence)
```

Even better, use `assert_raises()` in a `with` block.  See [How to use nose's assert_raises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767938/how-to-use-noses-assert-raises)

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
assert_raises(ParserError, parse_verb, raw_sentence)
```